# PHP echo does not run while in loop

Tags: php, debugging, phpunit, xdebug

I have a function in one of my phpunit tests that does this:

```
    echo "Order id: ".$order->id."\n";
    $email = $this->getOrderEmail($order->id);
    while($email === null) {
        echo "Sleeping for order id ".$order->id."\n";
        $this->saything();
        sleep(1);
        $email = $this->getOrderEmail($order->id);
    }
    echo "Got email: ".$email->MessageID."\n";
```

It runs the same code for several orders. The saything() method just echoes time().

When I run it, the first time it executes the code, it echoes correctly. When it runs it for the second order however, it echoes the "Got email", so I know it has exited the loop, and then it appears to stop processing.

When I use xdebug to trace the execution, I see that it is somehow still in the loop - it calls saything, which calls time(), and is supposed to echo it (literally: `echo time();`) - but doesn't. So the time() call is happening, but the echo() isn't. It hits the sleep, then the getOrderEmail, which returns null, triggering the loop to repeat but NOT echoing the "sleeping for..." message.

So I can clearly see in the xdebug trace that it is stuck in an infinite loop, but nothing is coming through to stdout! Why not? Could there be a bug in php somewhere? I've tried calling flush(), but that did nothing. How do I debug this? Also: How can it still be in the loop, when it has already executed the line following the loop? I've checked the process list, and it's definitely not forking, so I can't think of anyway it can exit a loop, while still being in the loop, and call echo without echoing anything.

I am aware that the problem is probablysomewhere else in the code, but it's way too big to post the whole thing here. Any ideas on how I can figure this out?

Comment: Remove the `sleep()` statement from inside the loop, add `var_dump($email);` to see how the value of `$email` changes on each iteration. When it becomes a non-null value, the loop iteration is stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From PHP Manual:

"flush() may not be able to override the buffering scheme of your web server and it has no effect on any client-side buffering in the browser. It also doesn't affect PHP's userspace output buffering mechanism. This means you will have to call both ob_flush() and flush() to flush the ob output buffers if you are using those."

You should try using [ob_flush()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php);

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear, this is being run from the command line - it's part of a phpunit test

Comment: Aaa! I can't believe it. ob_flush was what was needed - it would never have occurred to me that output buffering was active.

Comment: I believe you can also turn off output buffering in the PHP.ini